# chinese character insertion mysql

Tags: java, mysql, encoding, cjk

I am having problems inserting chinese characters in MySQL. I am able to insert the chinese characters only in Query Browser / Workbench, but it comes out as '??' when using my program. I somehow managed to get it to work on my computer (Windows 7) , but when I tested it on another (Windows 7 too) , it came out as question marks. It also won't work on a Windows XP Chinese. Any help?

Comment: Could it be that they need to be encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: " but it comes out as '??' when using my program". You'll need to present more information about the failure than this statement. Things that you ought to state are: the type of program that you've written (web-app, or JavaSE desktop app), the appropriate response headers you've set for a web-app, the locale of your desktop app, the font used to display the characters (in a browser/desktop app).

Comment: i have already set the collation of the database to utf-8.

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds I don't think it has something to do with the font, since the JLabels I wrote are completely readable. It is a JavaSE desktop app. The locale is EN in all computers, and I also added the statement `?characterSetResults=UTF-8&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useUnicode=yes` to the database URL because I saw it in some other post but it also wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The driver is transferring in UTF-8 seeing your comment on the connection string. The database table fields are probably specified UTF-8 too (check this).

So you have a normal Unicode string in Java. Check that by a dump of `String.getBytes("UTF-8")`. No question mark should appear.

In a web application you need to set the encoding before using the Writer. Otherwise you get such questing marks. Other possibilities to err are `String.getBytes()` (default OS encoding), Writer on a FileOutputStream using a StreamOutputStream also without encoding.

Answer (score 0):

1.use cmd to connect database 
for example:

```
D:\MySQL\bin>mysql -u root -D test -p
```

2.to change the database to UTF-8
for example:

```
mysql>alter database [database name] default character set utf8
```